# How to make custom buttons in Kivy with the KV Language?

Tags: python, button, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to use a custom sprite to make a custom button. I know how I can do this in the KV Language, but I'd rather stick with Python.

I saw that setting some source attribute to the sprite worked in the KV Language, so I tried this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class RoundButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.source = '/home/shamildacoder/Pictures/Painting.png'

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RoundButton(text='HELLO WORLD')

TestApp().run()
```

But this just shows a normal button. Any help?

Comment: What is source for? Do you want it to be the background of the image?

Comment: you could publish the .kv to make a translation to .py

Comment: No, I wan't the sprite to _be_ the button itself. like think there is a 16x16 image of a cartoon tree. when I press it, it works just like a button and calls the function bind to it. And i would like a Python answer directly without KV -> PY translation

Comment: is that your code suggests that you have based on a .kv code because source is an attribute of Image and not of Button, I proposed to make the translation so that you understand the correspondences and can work with other codes since the view is created in the .kv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you want an `Image` where you are allowed to handle the `on_press` event, for it the [`Behaviors`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.html) as I show below:

```
from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior  
from kivy.uix.image import Image  


class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class MyApp(App):  
    def build(self):  
        return ImageButton(source="kivy.png", on_press=lambda *args: print("press"))

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: `TypeError: __init__ takes no parameters`

Comment: @shamilpython Are you using only my code or are you adapting it to another code?

Comment: @shamilpython 
I have not called the constructor because it is not necessary for that reason I use `pass`.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, forgot to remove `text = 'Hello'`, fixed it. Thanks a lot!